# Laptop shut off during update from 14.04 to 16.04 LTS

Tags: updates

as the title says I was updating my software and I fell asleep. My laptop wasn't plugged in and now when I turn it on all I get is a black screen with a blinking white cursor. How can I fix this?
Thank you

Comment: do you see the BIOS or logo?

Comment: Have you tried a reboot? If so, like you said, it sounds like it shut off while trying to update/install packages. I hope you have a backup, because you probably have to reinstall. Even more, if you don't see the BIOS screen then your computer had a serious hardware bork.

Comment: There's a way of not loosing everything but I'll withhold that suggestion until further data is available.

Comment: I have a backup of my stuff, I just  don't see anything. All I see is the blinking cursor, is there any way to reinstall 16.04 LTS at this point?