# Black screen during update from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I closed the lid while it was updating. I previously removed the hibernation when the lid closes, but during update it asked me that file will be replaced, and I checked it YES.
After that I closed my lid, and now I am left with a black screen with a cursor. Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> gives a terminal, while <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> gives blank screen with cursor. What should I do? Please help. I have seen other suggestions but nothing is working.

I even tried restarting the *lightdm*, even after `swapoff -a` command but it is not working. Also I am getting some error of type

```
Unable to lock ... 
Could not get lock ...
```

Possible duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841325/laptop-shut-off-during-update-from-14-04-to-16-04-lts) but no solution is mentioned there. I do not want to lose my data. Please help. I fear to shut it down by pressing the power button as I was in the middle of upgradation.

Comment: In terminal try these steps [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/434635/reinstalling-ubuntu-via-terminal)

Comment: It says, "Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?"

Comment: find which process has a lock on it with `ps -aux | grep 'apt-get'`

Comment: lightdm has a lock on it

Comment: kill it `pkill -9 lightdm`. Then run through that link again

Comment: lightdm is the GUI. Are you sure I should kill it? As u see, I was in between the upgradation to 16.04

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56410/discussion-between-denominator-and-george).